# Using static method as JavaFX change listener

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

Can someone explain to me why this isn't working?

```
public class ListenerTest {
    public static void addListener(Node node) {
        node.visibleProperty().addListener(ListenerTest::handleVisibleChanged);
    }

    private static void handleVisibleChanged(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
            Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using Java 8 method reference to assign a static method as a JavaFX change listener. It compiles just fine, but handleVisibleChanged() method is not invoked when visible property changes.

Please don't offer workarounds or ask why am I doing this. Think of it as an exercise. :-)

Comment: That should work as expected - are you sure that the property is changed? Can you create a complete example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @assylias: Yes, I am quite sure that the property is changed. Complete example may take some time.

Comment: So if you put a `println` in your static method, it does not print anything?

Comment: @assylias: No, it doesn't. The method definitely does not get executed. Also, no error is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example that uses your two methods and works as expected: when the button is clicked, a message is printed.

```
public class ListenerTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label label = new Label("You can see me");
        addListener(label);
        Button button = new Button("Hide/Show");
        button.setOnAction(e -> label.setVisible(!label.isVisible()));

        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(20, label, button));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void addListener(Node node) {
        node.visibleProperty().addListener(ListenerTest::handleVisibleChanged);
    }
    private static void handleVisibleChanged(ObservableValue<?> a, Boolean b, Boolean newValue) {
        System.out.println("new value: " + newValue);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I get it now. Your example works because node is in the same class as the method, whereas in my case the method gets called from another class. I need to make **handleVisibleChanged** method public. Silly me.

Comment: @NikšaBaldun No that should not make a difference.

Comment: Actually, it does make a difference. I've made the method public and now it works. It probably comes down to a way that JavaFX calls the method, but I am too lazy to look at the source code. :-)

Comment: I can't reproduce that - even if I put the two static methods in a separate class and leave `handleVisibleChanged` private, the code still works.

Comment: Strange. In my case, **addListener** method is called from another class, and **node** is a private field in that class. It only works if I make **handleVisibleChanged** method public. It could be I am missing something, or it could be a bug in my version of JavaFX. Anyway, I don't have the time to investigate this further. Thanks for your help.